# Getting Data from API synchronously

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I am learning about async/sync concepts.

I have implemented async method to get data from an API which works fine. But I wanted to learn about synchronously calling API also.

I have written the following code which hangs my UI as I click on button to get data.

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        try
        {
            getData();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(""+ex);
        }
    }

    public void getData()
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/").Result;

            var data = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            PersonList contactdata = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PersonList>(data.Result.ToString());
            listcontact.ItemsSource = contactdata.contacts;
        }
    }
```

Which means it is running synchronously (I suppose). Please correct if I am wrong.

I want that it should show a progress ring until it gets data from API and then display it.

Is it possible?

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: use this `response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;`

Comment: @shu the op specifically asked wanting t make a synchrnus request :)

Comment: If you want to show progress then call it asynchronously and be done with it.  It's pointless having async code that merely calls `.Result`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making the request synchronously.

That means the thread on which the request was made will stop until you get the result.

The thing is, since your UI is launching the request, the entire UI thread (which was refreshing the UI) is waiting for the server's response.

If you want to do your request synchronously, without pausing the UI Thread you'll have to use a [`Task`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx) (or any other object allowing you to run your request on another thread)

```
var t = new Task(getData); //create the task, and tell it to run your method
t.Start(); //launch it
```

The task instance will allow you to get informations about the running task (if it is completed, cancelled, faulted) and in the case of a method returning a result, to get the return value of the method

Comment: I want to do like this as you suggested but how can you please elaborate how can implement some progress bar until the result is generated

Comment: @Vinita A progress bar will not be possible unless you have some way to know how advanced the operation is. If you do, you may use a Dispatcher/Event to notify your UI of the progress. If you do not know, you'll have to use an animation that does not reflect the progress (like the one used for windows 8+ boot)

Comment: Ok Thanks I just wanted to know  if that's possible. Rest of the code is working fine  by creating a task Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You should transform you call to use async version :

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Task.Run(() => getData());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(""+ex);
    }
}

public async Task getData()
{
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/");

        var data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        PersonList contactdata = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PersonList>(data.Result.ToString());
        listcontact.ItemsSource = contactdata.contacts;
    }
}
```

Like this, your call to button click will be async and should not block UI thread, and you can refresh it to show some progress.

If you run synchronously, you will block your UI thread. To show some progress within your getdata function, you can use events, or Dispatcher object.